# CefSharp - Replace Response Stream

Tags: c#, flash, stream, chromium, cefsharp

Hi StackOverflow Community

I'm currently working with CefSharp v79.1.36 (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) and I'm trying to replace a flash file with a modified version of it.

So far I'm using a ResponseFilter (as shown here https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/ExampleResourceRequestHandler.cs) and it's capturing the stream of the flash file.

---

The problem is: It's capturing the stream in chunks, not in one big stream. I can get the whole stream by override the OnResourceLoadComplete method, but I cannot modify the response in that method. And I need the whole stream before modifying it.

Anyone know if there's a way to modify the response stream after getting the whole stream?

---

Here's my code so far:

Set the Browser Custom Request Handler

```
RequestHandler requestHandler = new CustomBasicRequestHandler();
browser.RequestHandler = requestHandler;
```

CustomBasicRequestHandler

```
public class CustomBasicRequestHandler : RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        if (request.Url.Contains("MyFlashFile.swf"))
        {
            return new ExampleResourceRequestHandler();
        }

        //Default behaviour, url will be loaded normally.
        return null;
    }
}
```

ExampleResourceRequestHandler

```
public class ExampleResourceRequestHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
{
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;

    protected override bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        //NOTE: You cannot modify the response, only the request
        // You can now access the headers
        //var headers = response.Headers;

        return false;
    }

    protected override IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        if (response.MimeType == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
        {
            return new StreamResponseFilter(memoryStream);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
    {
        var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var dataLength = data.Length;
        // Got the whole Stream here, but cannot modify the response!
    }
}
```

StreamResponseFilter

```
public class StreamResponseFilter : IResponseFilter
{
    private Stream responseStream;

    /// <summary>
    /// StreamResponseFilter constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">a writable stream</param>
    public StreamResponseFilter(Stream stream)
    {
        responseStream = stream;
    }

    bool IResponseFilter.InitFilter()
    {
        return responseStream != null && responseStream.CanWrite;
    }

    FilterStatus IResponseFilter.Filter(Stream dataIn, out long dataInRead, Stream dataOut, out long dataOutWritten)
    {
        if (dataIn == null)
        {
            dataInRead = 0;
            dataOutWritten = 0;

            return FilterStatus.Done;
        }

        //Calculate how much data we can read, in some instances dataIn.Length is
        //greater than dataOut.Length
        dataInRead = Math.Min(dataIn.Length, dataOut.Length);
        dataOutWritten = dataInRead;

        var readBytes = new byte[dataInRead];
        dataIn.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
        dataOut.Write(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);

        //Write buffer to the memory stream
        responseStream.Write(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);

        //If we read less than the total amount avaliable then we need
        //return FilterStatus.NeedMoreData so we can then write the rest
        if (dataInRead < dataIn.Length)
        {
            return FilterStatus.NeedMoreData;
        }

        return FilterStatus.Done;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        responseStream = null;
    }
}
```

---

Thanks alot for any help :)

Comment: IResponseFilter will always filter data in chunks as that's how the underlying chromium implementation works. To provide your own response for a request see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-interception

Comment: Thanks alot amaitland for your help :) I've switched to a custom http scheme handler. This works fine for a flash stream, but as soon as I try the same for html content, the browser is displaying the content as plain text (I've set the MimeType of my ResourceHandler to "text/html"). Is there an example for a html resource handler like for the flash content (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/FlashResourceHandler.cs)?

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out (I've had to use ResourceHandler.GetMemoryStream):
`var receiveStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
var mime = httpWebResponse.ContentType;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, true);
Encoding encoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
string source = reader.ReadToEnd();
httpWebResponse.Close();
Stream stream = ResourceHandler.GetMemoryStream(source, encoding);`

Comment: The problem that the CefSharp Browser showed the content as plain text was:
`var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
MimeType = httpWebResponse.ContentType;`

So the mime type was set to "text/html charset=utf-8" which the browser somehow rendered as plain text. 

After doing this (inside ProcessRequestAsync):
`if (mime.Contains(';'))
                        {
                            mime = mime.Split(';')[0];
                        }
MimeType = mime;`

Which sets the mime type to "text/html", everything just renders fine.

Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: No that's not a bug, the CharSet should be set using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_ResourceHandler_Charset.htm you are welcome to submit a PR that improves the **example**